# Unexpected behavior with Calendar, SimpleDateFormat and Date

Tags: java

Given a date D, I am trying to create two Calendar instances for that day at the following UTC times: 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. My algorithm should work regardless of my timezone (mine is UTC+1) and, given the day of D, for that D the time has to be set.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

private static void f(Date date) {
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(date);
c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(date);
c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

//...
```

Then, I am trying to transform them into a UTC string with this code:

```
//...
String sc1 = fromDateToUTCString(c1.getTime());
String sc2 = fromDateToUTCString(c2.getTime());

System.out.println(sc1);
System.out.println(sc2);
}

public static String fromDateToUTCString(final Date date) {
    final String ISO_FORMAT = "yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
    final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

After this, the console prints 11:00:13 for c1 and 22:59:13 for c2.
JDK7.
The test main is trivial:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(new Date());
}
```

Why?

Comment: Do you mean `sc1` and `sc2` have the wrong seconds, or have `c1` and `c2` actually changed?

Comment: A short but complete program we could copy, compile and run would make it easier to understand this. It doesn't help that we don't know what `date` is either...

Comment: @Rup Not only the seconds, but also the hours (11 instead of 00 and 22 instead of 23)

Comment: @JonSkeet I slightly modified the code so that you can just call f from a main. I also included the imports: java.util.

Comment: "Very few programmers understand the state space of the Calender class.  I certainly don't." -- J. Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd Ed.

Comment: As well as providing a short but complete program, please tell us what your system time zone is. (It's also not clear whether you want the 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 to be in your system local time zone or UTC.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The program is complete, you can just copy it and call f from the main. I updated my post.

Comment: No, this is *not* a complete program. Heck, I don't even know what value of `date` you're using. I want to be able to have a single copy, paste-into-new-file, compile, run cycle - along with the results of you running that *exact same program*. I don't know why you're resisting this. I'm trying to help you.

Comment: I don't need a solution with a specific date. I need a solution that works with any date and regardless the timezone I am in. I am providing all the information I have.

Comment: @Manu This works as expected for me. We need more info to reproduce: what jdk version you are using, which timezone you are in, and what date you are using as input. You may not want a solution that works with a specific date, but knowing a specific date for which it does not work certainly helps to diagnose the problem.

Comment: As you haven't responded to my answer, when you want to create time valid for UTC, you should set the UTC as target time zone - *then* you are independent from the time zone you are in.

Comment: @Dima The date I am passing as input is the date of today. My TZ is UTC+1.

Comment: @Manu as you are unable to, I have added a sample program in my answer below - please correct your post if needed.

Comment: @Smutje: Even that's not a complete program - it doesn't contain a class declaration or imports. For me, "complete" means "I don't need to provide **any** more text".

Comment: @Manu still works for me: with timezone CET, I get  `2015-01-20T23:00:00` and `2015-01-21T22:59:59`, as expected. Give the actual *name* of the default timezone your system is using, and your jdk version. BTW, if you are looking for midnight UTC, you should be setting the timezone on the calendar as well as the format ... I am more interested in your other problem with the seconds offset.

Comment: On a completely different note - now might be a good time to change to using java.time (if you're using Java 8) or Joda Time (if you're not) both of which are *much* cleaner than java.util.{Date,Calendar}.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is your intention, but below code gives what you expect as the output.

```
    ...
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    c1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1*c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    c1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1*c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    c1.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1*c1.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    c2.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1*c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 23);
    c2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1*c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 59);
    c2.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1*c2.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 59); 
    ....

    //comment the time zone setting
    //sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
```

Output:

```
    2015-01-21T 00:00:00Z
    2015-01-21T 23:59:59Z
```

There is a `Z` at the end because of the format you have used. But actually the output is not in UTC.

**Update:**

With your code:

```
2015-01-20T16:30:00Z
2015-01-21T16:29:59Z
```

With your code + `-Duser.timezone=GMT` adding to JVM:

```
2015-01-21T00:00:00Z
2015-01-21T23:59:59Z
```

Comment: This leads to 2015-01-20T23:00:00Z 2015-01-21T22:59:59Z at my machine are you sure you are not in UTC so the offset does not apply to you?

Comment: Try with `-Duser.timezone=GMT` and then you can use `sdf.setTimeZone(utc);`

Comment: OP: "My algorithm should work regardless of my timezone (mine is UTC+1)"

Comment: did you tried with `c1.add()` rather than `c1.set()` ?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code. But it's not necessary, because I know the OPs problem, but he does somehow not want to check my answer.

Comment: I cannot add the Duser.timezone parameter.  Actually, your solution doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are not in UTC, so you're creating a time for timezone X and convert it to UTC afterwards. The solution is to create the `Calendar` objects *in* UTC:

```
c1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

respectively

```
c2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

## Complete Sample Program

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class CalendarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(new Date());
    }

    private static void f(Date date) {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(date);
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(date);
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        c2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        String sc1 = fromDateToUTCString(c1.getTime());
        String sc2 = fromDateToUTCString(c2.getTime());

        System.out.println(sc1);
        System.out.println(sc2);
    }

    public static String fromDateToUTCString(final Date date) {
        final String ISO_FORMAT = "yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
        final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
        return sdf.format(date);
    }
}
```

leads to

```
2015-01-21T00:00:00Z
2015-01-21T23:59:59Z
```

Comment: That makes sense, but an offset of 13 seconds (or -47 seconds) is very bizarre.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, at my machine (Germany), I got 23:00:00 and 22:59:59, so an offset of one hour.

Comment: Right. And that *might* be what the OP actually wants (i.e. the UTC representation of local times of 11am and 11pm). It's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Setting timezone on calendar shifts the other way. Besides, the issue is not  how to set the timezone but where the weird 13-second offset comes from.

Comment: @Dima from OP "Given a date, I am trying to create two Calendar instances for that day at the following UTC times: 00:00:00 and 23:59:59." so if he want to create UTC times, he should set the UTC zone.

Comment: @Smutje Your code shows the same values my code does.

Comment: @Manu very strange - your code produces your mentioned time zone offset error at my machine, but my code corrects this offset.